# Вычисление среднего числа трех long long в си

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, математика

Учитывая long long x, long long y и long long z, как можно вычислить ((x + y + z) / 3) с использованием полностью определенных операций в C, но исключая unsigned long long и более широкую арифметику?

Также я ограничен внесением изменений только внутри функции, которая должна найти среднее значение трех чисел.

Примечание: я уже пробовал искать решение, а также пробовал что-то вроде

```
#include <stdio.h>
long long average (long long a, long long b, long long c)
{
    long long n=0;
    n= a / 3 + b / 3 + c / 3 + (a % 3 + b % 3 + c % 3) / 3;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: а чем вариант в вопросе не понравился?

Comment: @Fat-Zer не правильно считает с данными в примере

Comment: УМВР: `4611686018427387900`... если числа задаёшь в коде, то суффикс `ll` не забыл добавить? и вывод через `%lld`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer у меня ассерт — assert (avg ( 9223372036854775800, 4611686018427387897, 3 ) == 4611686018427387900 );

Comment: добавь суффикс `ll` к литералам, иначе компилятор воспринимает их как `int`: `avg ( 9223372036854775800ll, 4611686018427387897ll, 3ll ) == 4611686018427387900ll)`

Comment: @Fat-Zer я ограничен на изменения в main func :(

Comment: У меня в `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`  ваш код выводит `4611686018427387900`, вычисления в `bc` дают `4611686018427387900`, т.е. похоже, что функция в тексте вопроса правильна. А что у вас?

Comment: @AlexXela, это прямая ошибка... без этого ни одна функция работать не будет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, вы уверены, что суффикс обязателен? Вроде бы, если суфикс не указан, то в качестве типа целочисленной константы будет взят самый первый тип из списка `int`, `long`, `long long`, который сможет вместить значение целочисленной константы.

Comment: @wololo, гм... посмотрел — похоже я здесь был не прав...

Answer (score 3):

Не воспроизводится.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

long long average (long long a, long long b, long long c)
{
    long long n=0;
    n= a / 3 + b / 3 + c / 3 + (a % 3 + b % 3 + c % 3) / 3;
    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    long long a=9223372036854775800;
    long long b=4611686018427387897;
    long long c=3;

    printf("%lld\n", average(a, b, c));
    printf("%lld\n", 4611686018427387900);

    assert (average ( 9223372036854775800, 4611686018427387897, 3 ) == 4611686018427387900 );
}
```

https://ideone.com/Cm2vKo

> 4611686018427387900
> 4611686018427387900

Comment: а что если будут числа 9223372036854775800, -6, -2 ? тога ответ уже не верный выписвает,  на единицу больше

Answer (score 0):

может так попробовать?

```
const long long x1 = a >> 32;
const long long x2 = a  & 0xFFFFFFFF;

const long long y1 = b >> 32;
const long long y2 = b & 0xFFFFFFFF;

const long long z1 = c >> 32;
const long long z2 = c & 0xFFFFFFFF;

res = (((x1 + y1 + z1) / 3) << 32) + (x2 + y2 + z2) / 3;
```

Comment: для отрицательных чисел в Си — UB...

Comment: @Zhihar посмотри что выводит с тестовыми чисмлами, у меня совсем другое число в ответе

Comment: @Alex Xela, да, по сравнению с тем что дал виндовый калькулятор ошибка составила 3,1e-8

надо подумать - причина понятна - это сработало отбрасывание дробной части в старших разрядах

Comment: @Zhihar, `res = (((x1 + y1 + z1) / 3) << 32) + ((((x1+y1+z1)%3) << 32) + x2 + y2 + z2) / 3;`...

Answer (score 0):

```
long long average (long long a, long long b, long long c)
{   
    int digits[100];
    memset(digits, 0, sizeof(int) * 100);
    
    // сложить 3 числа
    int pos = 0;
    
    int flag = 0;
    
    while (a != 0 || b != 0 || c != 0) {
        const int d1 = a % 10;
        a /= 10;
    
        const int d2 = b % 10;
        b /= 10;
    
        const int d3 = c % 10;
        c /= 10;
    
        const int res = d1 + d2 + d3 + flag;
        flag = res / 10;
    
        digits[pos++] = res % 10;
    }
    
    digits[pos++] = flag;
    
    
    // разделить на 3
    int digits_res[100];
    int pos_res = 0;
    
    int sum = 0;
    
    for (int index = pos - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        const int digit = digits[index];
    
        sum = sum * 10 + digit;
    
        digits_res[pos_res++] = sum / 3;
    
        sum = sum % 3;
    }
    
    
    // собрать в число
    long long res = 0;
    
    for (int index = 0; index < pos_res; index++)
        res = res * 10 + digits_res[index];
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: возможно это все засунуть в функцию? я не ограничен изменениями только в фунцкии над main func :(

Comment: @Alex Xela, засунул - скорректировал код

Comment: можешь плз еще чуть пофиксить, слишком много erorrs

Comment: У меня ошибок не было, какие ошибки?

Comment: уже ок, но что если я не могу юзать массивы, доп библиотеку и memset func принадлежащий ей?

Comment: @Alex Xela, ну вместо `memset` что вам мешает в цикле заполнить массив нулями? Я просто через эту функцию код на 2 строчки сократил, а касательно нельзя юзать массив - это как? вы работаете с массивом при сортировке, а что тогда юзать?

Comment: возможно это звучит невероятно, но референс решения не содержит массива ))

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код не учитывает работу с отрицательными числами.

Пусть квадратные скобки `[...]` обозначают операцию отбрасывания дробной части вещественного числа, `a`, `b`, `c` — целые вещественные числа, тогда:

[image: Формула №1]

Введём обозначения:

[image: Формула №2]

Тогда получим:

[image: Формула №3]

Заметим, что `x`, `y` — целые числа, а модуль значения `y/3` принадлежит полуинтервалу `[0, 1)`. В зависимости от знаков значений `x` и `y` итоговый результат будет следующим:

```
x == 0 || y == 0  =>  result == x,
x > 0 && y > 0    =>  result == x,
x > 0 && y < 0    =>  result == x-1,
x < 0 && y > 0    =>  result == x+1,
x < 0 && y < 0    =>  result == x.
```

Таким образом, функция нахождения среднего значения будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
long long average(long long a, long long b, long long c)
{
    long long rem_sum = a % 3 + b % 3 + c % 3;
    long long x = a / 3 + b / 3 + c / 3 + rem_sum / 3;
    long long y = rem_sum % 3;

    int coef1 = -(x > 0 && y < 0);
    int coef2 = +(x < 0 && y > 0);

    return x + coef1 + coef2;
 }
```

Ну, и несколько проверок:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 long long average(long long a, long long b, long long c){...}

 int main(void)
 {
    long long min = -9223372036854775807 - 1;
    long long max = 9223372036854775807;

    printf("%d", average(min, min,   min)   ==  min         );
    printf("%d", average(max, max,   max)   ==  max         );
    printf("%d", average(min, min+1, min+2) ==  min+1       );
    printf("%d", average(max, max-1, max-2) ==  max-1       );
    printf("%d", average(max,  1,     2)    ==  max/3 + 1   );
    printf("%d", average(max, -1,    -2)    ==  max/3 - 1   );
    printf("%d", average(min,  1,     2)    == -(max/3 - 1) );
    printf("%d", average(min, -1,    -2)    == -(max/3 + 1) );
    printf("%d", average(0,    0,     0)    ==  0           );
    printf("%d", average(2,    2,     2)    ==  2           );
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("%d", average(9223372036854775800, 4611686018427387897, 3) == 4611686018427387900);
    printf("%d", average(9223372036854775800, -6, -2) == 3074457345618258597);
    printf("\n");
 
    long long counter = 0;
    long long first = -32;
    long long last =   32;
    for (long long a = first; a <= last; ++a)
        for (long long b = first; b <= last; ++b)
            for (long long c = first; c <= last; ++c)
            {
                long long res = (a + b + c) / 3;
                if (average(a, b, c) != res)
                    ++counter;
            }
    printf("Errors: %lld\n", counter);
}
```

[Вывод](https://ideone.com/hz9eHw):

```
1111111111
11
Errors: 0
```